# Seamless account creation on StackExchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-openid

If try to create an account in any StackExchange site, you will be presented with a signup page, which has Google, Facebook, and StackExchange as signup options.

> [image: Signup page]

When you choose and click Google/Facebook, if you are already logged into that website you will eventually arrive at the *create account* page. Your browser will be redirected few times, but the process is seamless.

> [image: Create account page]

But, if I choose the StackExchange option, I am required to fill an account creation form, even if I am already logged into StackExchange.

So my question is, why is StackExchange does not do the same as Google and Facebook? In other words, why I have to give username/passwords when I am already logged into StackExchage? As far as I know all services implement the same protocol.

Edit: Clicking `login` instead of `signup` takes you to a different page, which has less fields for SE option. But again, Facebook and Google options are seamless.

> [image: Log in]

I expect that when I click SE option for login/signup, it should redirect me to SE site, and if I'm already logged into SE, I should be again redirected to the site I was at the first place. Facebook and Google auth options do this.

Comment: Just click "log in" instead of "sign up"

Comment: If you click the "More signup options" link and fill in `https://openid.stackexchange.com` in the OpenId input area, you will get the exact same experience.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: login prompts up a username/password field pair.

Comment: @Oded: typing in a URL? Not the definition of _seamless_.

Comment: @Krumia that's right, so not sure what you expect?

Comment: I expect that when I click SE option for login/signup, it should redirect me to SE site, and if I'm already logged into SE, I should be again redirected to the site I was at the first place. Facebook and Google auth options do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is sort of done. I say "sort of" because we didn't go back to treating StackId as the OpenID it really is behind the scenes. There's just no graceful way to make that work without changing up the UI to hide email/password fields behind another click. Besides, we'd be removing the ability to easily log into multiple StackId-powered Q&A accounts without explicitly going back to log out of StackId.

However, with [the universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) now in place, you no longer need to "log in" or "sign up" when you visit a site you don't have a profile on while already logged in. Just click "join this community" in the top bar and you should be all good to go without having to re-enter any credentials.