# Global auth is dead! Long live universal login

Tags: discussion, login, auto-login

> **Update: Universal login is in place and considered "done". If you see anything weird, please submit new bug reports.**

---

As y'all know, our current flavor of "global authentication" leaves a few things to be desired. It's flaky, requires a page refresh, etc. etc. Wouldn't it be nice if you could just sign in once and be automatically logged in across the network?

[image: Good news, everyone!]

We are ready to roll out **Stage 1 of Project "Make Authentication Suck Less"**. It is live as of a few minutes ago.

#### What this means *right now*:

1. When you log into any Q&A site on the stackexchange.com domain, you will be automatically logged into all other Q&A sites on the stackexchange.com domain + stackexchange.com itself.

   - [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is excluded from this.
2. [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/), and other Q&A sites with their own domains will still use the old flow.
3. We are going to recognize you *in some ways* on sites where you don't have a profile. This is still a work in progress, but most notably you will see "join this community" in the top bar instead of "sign up" and "log in" if you're logged in on another site on our network. Clicking the button will create a profile on that site and link it with your network account.

#### But I use multiple accounts! What do?

We aren't intending to break the ability to run multiple accounts. The same guidelines as before still apply — we don't officially support that, you might end up with an accidental automatic merge if you're not careful with your credentials, any interaction between the accounts is right out, and so on.

If you're already using different browsers or different browser profiles for your accounts, nothing will change for you. If you are somehow logged into multiple accounts in the same browser... I'm sorry to say, but that's a bug even for our current global auth setup. You will now only be able to log into one at a time, and you'll need to log out when you want to switch. (Or start using different browsers.)

#### What's next:

- Remember [the UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/new-year-new-experiment-login-and-signup-ui) we tested a few months ago? It's coming back.
- Stage 2: bring other domains into the fold (this is also live now)
- <s>Stage 3: make cross-domain experience smoother and support browsers that reject third-party cookies in all conditions (looking at you, Safari)</s> - this is not currently feasible. Safari users and users who reject third-party cookies will need to sign in separately to every second-level domain (e.g. stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, etc).

#### If you see any issues…

Good luck, because you probably can't log in to report them here. =) But seriously, let us know via the contact form linked at the bottom of any page. If you *are* able to log in, report issues here on meta as normal.

#### So, in conclusion…

[image: Brace yourselves, universal login is coming]

Comment: Beyond the "join this community" link, can you elaborate on "We are going to recognize you in some ways on sites where you don't have a profile."?

Comment: @MonicaCellio There's not much else to say right now, but there have been feature requests floating around along the lines of "make my inbox follow me around the network" that will be possible once this work is complete. Whether or not we're gonna do them (or something else) is still undecided. We are *not* going to create profiles on every site for users without their consent.

Comment: Thanks.  It sounded like you had more in mind for the immediate future.  (In many ways I like the idea of the top bar following me around, so to speak, but I'd like something more obvious than the text of one link to tell me whether I'm actually a user, and logged in, on a site. Where should I leave that kind of feedback, since I suspect this isn't the right place?)  Meanwhile, thanks for making cross-site stuff easier for us!

Comment: Hey Adam, just wanted to say thanks for this. You've probably spent a half a year plus on this... and I think it'll be a lot better. Thanks. :)

Comment: @hichris123 I have. :) It's been... interesting. Probably decent fodder for a blog post on technical details later. Geoff Dalgas is working on this as well and there's light at the end of the tunnel (that probably isn't a train)!

Comment: @MonicaCellio For the moment, feel free to leave feedback as answers or comments here. There's also gonna be room for feature requests and whatnot (as we normally treat them) as separate posts once this is fully live and everyone's had a chance to kick the tires on the new system for a while.

Comment: Does this mean north.stackexchange and east.stackexchange with separate account logins for each site by the same person will be auto-linked/joined?

Comment: @random Nothing is changing in terms of account/profile handling. You can still have multiple accounts (assuming you know your way around OpenID quirks) and you still have to opt in to join an individual site.

Comment: Hey Adam, Thank you for this great news! Quick question, so if I logout from any of Q&A sites, would that also log me out from all the sites too?

Comment: @HackerKarma Yes... eventually.

Comment: And will logging out also log people out of the SE OpenID provider? Personally, I use Google, but for those using SE's internal OpenID, the fact that it's treated as internal in the UI (login form loads inline) but external in terms of logging out is confusing and probably a security flaw.

Comment: Stage 1 of Project "Make Authentication Suck Less" - MASL; now that's what I call an abbreviation. ;P

Comment: I was just about to post a feature request asking for this!

Comment: When I login on stackexchange.com, it will then log me on any site,  or it would happen once I visit some SE site,  i.e. site by site?

Comment: @nicael It will log you in on every site at the stackexchange.com domain (that is, not Stack Overflow or Super User, etc. - that's the next stage of this project.)

Comment: And update my "seen" field too?

Comment: @nicael Your "seen" field will only be updated on the sites you actually visit.

Comment: For a long time I have been using openid to log in on stackexchange sites using stackexchange as the openid provider. That meant I only had to type my password on the openid login page and then I would be logged in on all the stackexchange sites where I have a profile.

Comment: MASL tov, and smooth deployment!

Comment: If I logged in here in meta last week, and I've never logged in on (say) codereview, will that mean that now my session is started there too? Or do I have to re-login for my session to 'expand' across all sites?

Comment: Hey I am not able to login. How to report? =)

Comment: "Good news" in Comic Sans? That's impossible!

Comment: If you're already in there, can you please have the login redirect back to `http://` version of the site? Right now it redirects to `https://` version which is not supported and many things break in weird places.

Comment: [Will this be finally fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209605/179541)? `</poke>`

Comment: Also, worth adding that SEDE won't be affected by this.

Comment: Will chat be covered by this as well?

Comment: Will I be able to choose which sites (where I have an account) I log in to or will it be automagic ?

Comment: @Raphael Chat will be covered, yes.

Comment: @Iain http://i.stack.imgur.com/IneV2.gif

Comment: Cheers, looks like I'll be creating an account per site then so I don't get logged in when and  where I don't want to be.

Comment: Any chance we will see Microsoft Account as an option to login?

Comment: Please, while changing the login, is it possible to make it work not to be constantly logged out when visiting SO with an iPad?

Comment: @Iain You'll still be anonymous (that is, without a user profile) on the sites you haven't explicitly joined. We aren't pre-creating profiles for anyone.

Comment: I found it ironic that when I clicked to upvote this post, I was prompted to log in to meta.se. :)

Comment: Its really about time, I really hate the log in process that is currently there, it looks like it was really rushed and it just has a lot of quirks.

Comment: I understand that Adam, I just want to be able to choose when and where I log in (or not). For example don't really want to log in to SF if I happen to land there and happen to be logged in here.

Comment: @Iain Out of curiosity, why not? Right now you would still be logged in to SF automatically (assuming you didn't go out of your way to block current global auth), just after a page refresh.

Comment: I don't go out of my way to block auth that I'm aware. I'm logged out of SF on this device.  I'm logged in here, I can open a tab with SF in and I don't get logged in. I can exit this browser, start it again and go to SF and not get logged in. Load a tab with mSE and I'm logged in. Go back to the tab with SF refresh etc stay logged out.

Comment: @Iain Sounds like a [common law feature](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).

Comment: @reirab Also related: http://cube-drone.com/comics/c/ingeniuty-of-sorts. There are definitely enough quirks/failures in the current system that folks have come to rely on them. As far as I know, Iain (and others in similar situations) should be getting logged in on SF after logging in on Meta or another Q&A site in the network, but why it's not actually happening... who knows.

Comment: @AdamLear LOL! Ok, I'm saving that one. That's great.

Comment: You guys _do_ know what kind of mess "good news, everyone" by Prof. Farnsworth usually results in, right?

Comment: What is "stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, etc."? Most of the sites? Or just the original trilogy, before the merge with Stack Exchange 1.0? Or the sites with their own domain names?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sites with their own domain names.

Comment: I already have universal login thanks to Wordpress, but it's nice to know you guys are actively trying to improve stuff.

Comment: Sadly my 2 accounts got merge yesterday.

Comment: Is the implementation of this opensource, or been reviewed with an eye to security? There are many many things that could go wrong, and many things that very often *do*. Even with SEI's fantastic developers, it is likely that there are some security bugs - I wouldn't go try to hack on it without permission, but it is something that should be considered.

Comment: Does this affect the [Fanatic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) badge so I earn it once, I earn it on all sites? "Visit" potentially != "login", but how is a visit counted if not by login?

Comment: @Thomas No, visits have never been tied to logging in. We track actual page visits for that badge.

Comment: @AviD The implementation is pretty strongly tied to our code, so it's hard to open source. We *are* reviewing it for vulnerabilities with as many eyes as we can muster up internally, though.

Comment: @deadlydragon00 Your accounts shared an email address. That'd have been picked up eventually prior to these changes as well.

Comment: @AdamLear is it too early to shed any light on exactly what technologies will be utilized this time?

Comment: @AdamLear I don't see "join this community" on http://mathoverflow.net (where I don't have an account). Was MO forgotten by any chance, or is it not a part of the plan?

Comment: @1999 Crossing domains is the most annoying part of this. We haven't quite decided if we're going to log you in to all domains you don't already have a profile on or not. (At the moment, it's the latter.) Stage 3 should allow us to alleviate some of this... But there's always going to be an opportunity for failure.

Comment: @AdamLear The top part of the question is out of date now... if I understand right the second item in the list should just be merged into the first one, leaving area51 as the exception? (and there's the obvious "stage 1 is live" bit)

Comment: Area 51, for no particular reason, is excluded from the global login. Yay! It also gives you the wrong gravatar and won't let you change it. Yay! What is up with A51? Did the aliens mess up the internals?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms There is a whole list of reasons why it's excluded. The main one being... it can't (right now) talk to the database it'd need to talk to to be included, and making that work is rather non-trivial. I have a plan for a workaround that involves using private APIs, but it's also not ideal... I suppose A51 could be a "stage 4" of this project. No promises, though.

Comment: @AdamLear I thought that might be the case. I think it would be worthwhile for you guys to fit Area 51 into the system a little better, it seems a tad removed, disconnected and trouble some. It also gave issues with the new profiles...

Comment: Is there any plan to include the SO careers site in this as well?

Comment: @salniro Very, very vague plans. Careers has some other considerations (such as "is this person a developer looking for a job or an employer") and, currently, a completely separate login/auth system from the Q&A sites. We'd like to unify these at some point, but it's a pretty hefty project in and of itself.

Comment: I assume this is a big step forward on getting HTTPS to work on the entire Stack Exchange network. Or am I wrong? Then at some point my selfish thoughts of not sharing my delicious cookies with anyone might become reality :-) Nice work!

Comment: Should I really be seeing the "questions, answers, points mean prizes, please take the 2-minute tour now" banner on a site if I'm known in the network but not a member of that particular site? (One might assume you already know the general principle if you're a network member.)

Comment: wonder if new login could make it easier to [help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)

Comment: @gnat Not easily... although I suppose not as hard as it would be before. This doesn't change the fact that a question block is a transient, not a persistent state. Running a "can this user post?" check every time they go to another site is bad, not to mention that they could, in theory, be unaware of the block and going to ask a legitimate question elsewhere.

Comment: I see, thanks. What about [performing automatic checks for cross-posting and question block at SO when post enters close queue (not only at attempt to migrate)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6795/31260)? ("to account for possibly unpredictable amount of questions that may enter the queue, system can be limited to some reasonable fixed amount of checks, like 30-50 a day")

Comment: Can we get subdomains of stackexchange.com even for sites that have their own domain? I find it kind of annoying that I have to exempt all those domains from cookie blocking to be able to log in.

Comment: @BlacklightShining They have aliases, but there's more or less no way we're going to switch away from those domains for all sites that have them. Stack Overflow especially, but even Server Fault, Super User, etc. have a pretty solid brand at this point. We're years too late to make that kind of a change.

Comment: @AdamLear Yeah, I'm not asking for the canonical domain to change, just for a choice. Something like `stackoverflow.stackexchange.com` being the same as `stackoverflow.com` (though not _redirecting_; that would defeat the purpose).

Comment: Now all that's left is extending the automatic login and account synchronization to SEDE.

Answer (score 134):

Has this been tested by someone who has two disparate accounts?

- one account, email address A, used on sites B and C
- second account, email address D, used on sites E and F only

Today I can click links or type addresses and am recognized as A on sites B and C and as D on sites E and F no problem. I can go back and forth between them in the same browser. There is talk that such accounts sometimes get automerged, but I've been doing this a long time and that hasn't happened. A good thing too, because **I don't want to it to happen**. My D account is separate for a reason and it would be a HUGE violation of my privacy (retrospectively) for posts from that account to be relabelled with my A account (this one.)

So, has this scenario been tested and shown to work the same way today's login process does?

Comment: We don't officially support multiple accounts, but we're also not going out of our way to break them. You are still welcome to run as many accounts as you want (so long as they don't interact - I know you know this, but I'm including this note for completeness' sake), but you will have to log out/log in when you want to switch between the two (or use two different browsers). Having said that... I'm trying to figure out how you logged into two different accounts at the same time given how current global auth works. :) Mind if I shoot you an email to discuss specifics?

Comment: sure! I believe you know my address already :-)

Comment: Thanks again for bringing this up - I'll be sure to add a note to the post once changes are rolled out with tips/help/instructions for multi-account users.

Comment: Multiple accounts was working for me, one is an openid provider and the other is a stackexchange login, both login me in separately automatically. Other than using the same computer SO shouldn't know that they are in anyway linked. Wasn't that the whole point of openID - I don't want to trust a site with my details so they can track my other online activities?

Comment: Agreed. My main account can be tied to me real-world identity (by my own choice); where I to inquire about a sensitive matter on, say, [academia.SE], [workplace.SE] or [parenting.SE], I would want another account.

Comment: @AdamLear Can't you have site-specific cookies that override the global one? Another idea would be to have one login, but several identities. Only staff (and maybe mods) would be able to tell two identities used the same login. Users would have to choose one identity per site they want to join. (So I could be Raphael on my "home site" [cs.SE] but AnonymousAngryGradStudent on [academia.SE].)

Comment: Yeah, this is borked. I use a different Google account for SE sites on some more "frivolous" topics. It used to work just great. Now my other account is recognized at those sites and it wants to log me in with this one. Not happy that I'm going to need to fire up a different browser.

Comment: @AlE. You can always use safe / incognito mode.

Comment: Having multiple profiles in Chrome has worked well for my Google accounts (one for personal, one for business), and I don't have to suffer through the loss of cookies in incognito mode. Logging in to both accounts from a single profile worked fine for gmail but had issues when I wanted to log into the Google Play Store and it insisted on using the primary (/u/0/) account. You end up with two browser windows -- same as incognito -- but everything works correctly.

Comment: Multifox can be used to have different sessions in tabs of the same browser window.

Comment: Before this comment area gets locked to prevent "Hip hip hooray!" pile ons, let me just say, "Hip Hip HOORAY!"  Thank you to all who have been sweating the details on this.

Comment: Just use Multifox or similar. This is the only real solution for the "multiple accounts" problem. We should stop demanding individual sites to support this workflow and start demanding better support on the browser side.

Answer (score 41):

In the Drop Down it still asks to log in

[image: In the Drop Down it still asks to log in]

Answer (score 39):

The announcement reminded me very soon about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210961/keeping-the-top-bar-logged-in) request.

I hope it's the right time to consider it now - it would be great to see the inbox / achievements indicator in the top bar (on the places they are when you're logged in) along with the "join this community" link you've said will be added. I think it wouldn't be a trouble to implement it, supposing that this

> We are going to recognize you in some ways on sites where you don't have a profile.

is going to happen.

Comment: `I hope it's the right time to consider it now` - almost! The right time will be after this project is fully done. :)

Comment: @Adam so it will be added (please?)  as an appendix to the fully completed project? Fine then =)

Comment: No promises at this stage.

Comment: @nicael Sure, in 6-8 weeks

Answer (score 33):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) <sub><sup>(as of rev 2015.7.13.3577 on meta, 2015.7.13.2722 elsewhere)</sup></sub>

That's great! So, let's go to some site where I don't have an account (but actually I do have everywhere, so I had to delete one of the unused :D)

If you are on the main site, you can see:

> [image]

But if you are on the per-site meta, you'll see the usual "sign up / log in":

> [image]

Though it's possible to click "log in" which takes you to the main site login and then click "join this community", maybe I should be able to directly use the new "join" feature from the per-site meta too?

Comment: Good point, will fix.

Answer (score 24):

If I go to [/users/logout on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/logout), it says:

> Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out of English Language Learners Stack Exchange on all devices.

Which is true, but it also logs me out just about everywhere else.  Shouldn't it say so?

Comment: Yes, it certainly should. I'll be updating logout copy tomorrow.

Comment: @AdamLear I noticed it didn't yet - was this something that fell of the long list? :P

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With stage 1 live here is a scenario that doesn't let you log in once logged out.

Repro steps in Chrome on Win7:

1. clear all cookies/session storage
2. goto meta.stackexchange.com
3. click login
   (I use google)
4. I'm logged in
5. From the menu choose Log Out
6. Click the Log Out button
7. You're logged out
8. click Login
   (I use google)
9. I'm **not** logged in

I can iterate step 7 and 8 but I never get logged in. Only after pressing F5 I am able to login again.

One other thing I noticed which I'm not sure if this is related. This dev console shows:

> POST https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login/global/request 404 (not found)

whenever I try to login.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. (This will be a fun afternoon... :))

Comment: I repro-ed on FF as well, with the difference that hitting F5 is not enough, I really need to navigate to a different site and then return to be able to login again

Comment: Norepro with SE login.

Answer (score 12):

SEDE seems to be logging me out every day (even though I've been on multiple stacks every day), and my SEDE account doesn't seemed to be linked to my other accounts at all.

Will these next round of changes fix that too? If no, could we have that improvement as well?

Comment: No, SEDE is open source, totally separated from the sites.

Comment: Feel free to create a PR to fix that...

Comment: Open source or not, it's still part of stackexchange.com and for such I would expect a common (working) login.

Comment: @rene It's actually [a deployment issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182256/extend-or-remove-dataexplorer-timeout)

Comment: @TimStone Hmmm, looking at the timeframe of both the posts and chat messages, is there anything we (maybe I) can do to make this easier/doable for the deployment engineers without compromising their main concern of leaking the machinekey?

Comment: @rene Make sure I stop forgetting to ask Nick about it? :P

Comment: Oh believe me, you don't want **THAT** @TimStone

Answer (score 12):

After the recent issue with the CSS (or rather, lack thereof) for the [new question close statistics tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257449/new-10k-tool-question-close-statistics) on sites that don't yet have the [new base CSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed), and a similar issue with the new image uploader, I've got a request.

Please test this on sites that don't have the new base CSS, to ensure ye olden sites won't have issues with users logging in.

Comment: Yep yep, I'm on it. :) This page is designed to have its own styling, without site chrome at all, so it *should* be good, but it's been a few months since we ran it last, so I'll definitely be checking how it's holding up.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this has been mentioned, but I tried to upvote the original post without having first clicked "join this community" and I got the usual "log in first" box, with options to Sign up via Google, Facebook, Stack Exchange, etc.  However, it didn't have any option to "Join this community" like at the top of the site.  Should that be added as an option?

I feel that would be a nice addition.  I didn't notice the "Join this Community" link before I read @nicael's post.

[image: When trying to upvote, etc. on a community to which I am not a member yet.]

Comment: Yep, that's on the list. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, great work so far, I really like this new feature!  So much easier.  Keep up the good work with everything!  ^_^

Answer (score 10):

It will be better, but I think if you should make an option where users can give **permission to auto login** or global login in **some Stack Exchange community**, I mean, if you don't want to auto login in some Stack Exchange community then you can **disable auto login** for only that Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 10):

Logging out is now broken if you have accounts on multiple sites which are simultaneously logged in.

If I log out of one site, I need to log out of *all* Stack Exchange sites to have it actually be remembered.

Otherwise, every time I visit a site I have just logged out of it will automatically log me in. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73686/193412) meta post suggests a "log out everywhere" functionality but I don't know where it is. There are [other meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108161/193412) talking about similar but different functionality.

I am not sure how I can successfully log out of a Stack Exchange site indefinitely (let alone all of them at once) with this new login change.

I am logged into numerous sites on the SE network currently.

Navigating to here, and clicking "log out":

[image]

Hitting "log out" then results in success:

[image]

However, immediately clicking "Questions" twice then logs me back in on The Workplace. If I navigate to another SE page, such as Meta.SE, it seems I only have to click Questions once.

It seems too that I am temporarily logged out of Meta as doing this has required me to refresh this page to edit (I got errors uploading images immediately after logging out on Workplace) but refreshing Meta.SE caused me to be logged into Meta.

I am using Google Chrome.

After logging out, I see a lot of Stack Exchange related cookies still (not sure what else to search for them):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not see the workplaceusr or meusr ones however.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, you *should* be getting logged out of all of them at once. There's no option to log out of just one site. Can you be more specific about your steps here and which sites are involved?

Comment: @AdamLear I added the steps I am following, sorry for making a bad bug report ;)

Comment: Do you have a "workplaceusr" cookie or "mseusr" cookie?

Comment: @AdamLear after logging out on Meta.StackExchange (my only open SE site in my Chrome at this point) I see a _lot_ of SE cookies. I searched "meta" and saw a full listing of them. After logging out here I also see 4 cookies for workplace.stackexchange.com and 1 for meta.workplace.stackexchange.

Comment: What are their names? I'm looking for specific ones here.

Comment: @AdamLear neither of those two are here. I added images of _some_ of the ones I still see, there may be other Stack Exchange cookies I did not think to search for or see.

Comment: What happens if you log out and then clear cookies for all SE domains?

Answer (score 5):

The code to detect the login status on other sites is flawed.

I'm currently logged in on Stackoverflow, This meta, CodeReview, AskUbuntu and many others.
Worth mentioning that this login was made over 2 months ago. Always the same session.

And today, I got a link to visit this:

[Review+Edit Page](https://stackapps.com/questions/4848/reviewedit-page)

But, instead of the nice `join this community` button, I had the login and signup buttons.

If I go to a *.stackexchange.com website, I get this:

[image: Anime screenshot]

Nothing wrong there, the nice button is there.

Now, on StackApps:

[image: Stackapps]

And on MathOverflow:

[image: MathOverflow]

So, the detection code is broken only on 'external' websites.

---

Currently, to showcase this, I'm using Firefox 39.0 running on Windows 7x64 SP1.

Any other informations will be gladly provided.

---

### Update!

As of today I can confirm it is working flawlessly! I can see the expected behaviour and everything is working as it should.

Thank you for fixing this!

Comment: Yeah, this is a side-effect of how we rolled this out... and how stage 2 works. Right now, we only log you into the domains you already have a profile on. My goal is to convince Geoff Dalgas to send auth requests to all custom domains, although even if/when we do that, there will still be a chance of failure. We're going to try and make this as fool-proof as possible before we call this "done", though.

Comment: @AdamLear I though this was addressed already. According to the list, this is already solved.

Comment: It is if you explicitly log in (as opposed to having been "upgraded" into the new system) *and* if none of the requests fail *and* you have accounts on all custom domains we have. So, sort of, but not entirely.

Comment: @AdamLear That should be added to the question. I had no idea about that tiny detail. And most don't too, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the privacy of the users, I think the current situation is better, even if it requires more effort from the users. **If you want to login on a site, you should do it explicitly. If not, it must not happen automatically**, when you have logged into to other site.

So, it maybe a bad news for privacy advocates.

Comment: Could you elaborate in what way this affects privacy? You can always use your browser's incognito/privacy mode if you want to visit a site while being truly logged out.

Comment: To be clear: **this doesn't create a user for you**, it will only do universal login you in *if you have one*. We have no plans at all to auto-create users, we agree that's terribad.

Comment: I understand. Consider the situation that I want to be logged in abc.stackexchange.com, but I don't want to be logged in xyz.stackexchange.com. If I want, I can login on my will. Login should be tak place upon explicit request of the user.

Comment: That's... not exactly how it works right now. It should (at the present) automatically log you in, but then you have to refresh the page. In the future, even that would be simpler.

Comment: As the post says: "When you log into any Q&A site on the stackexchange.com domain, you will be automatically logged into all other Q&A sites on the stackexchange.com domain + stackexchange.com itself". So, if I want to login to abc.stackexchange.com, I can not avoid logging into other subdomains of this domain. There should be local authentication, and global authentication. One that logs into the stackexchange.com should be different from the one that logs into abc.stackexchange.com. If this is what is going to happen, I appreciate that.

Comment: @Ho1 *"So, if I want to login to abc.stackexchange.com, I can not avoid logging into other subdomains of this domain"* That is correct, and how things have been for a while now.

Comment: @KevinB Are you sure? Cookies are set for specific subdomains, and not the top level domain. Right now, I am logged into meta.stackexchange.com but I am not in apple.stackexchange.com (which I also have an account). And I appreciate this behaviour. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: If you have an account there, and go there after being logged in here, it will log you in and a bar will appear at the top of the site telling you that you are now logged in, assuming the account is using the same openid or email.

Comment: @KevinB When I have an account on site A and logged out there on a previous visit, I wouldn't want to be logged in automatically when I go there again just because I'm logged in on site B. In other words: I wouldn't want a global auto-log-in.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do it if you logout.

Comment: @TehMacDawg You wouldn't want it? You already have it, they're just making it suck less.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I just tested that, and no, I'm not automatically logged back in on a site where I logged out before. — If this were to happen, it  would be a *huge* change as it would practically be the elimination  of user-controlled site-wise log-in/out… Could you test it yourself? I'm not sure if this might be the Safari thing, or because I'm using one of the third-party ID options for login.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist OK, the current state: If I'm logged in specifically on the top domain 'stackexchange.com', I automatically get logged in on any subdomain I go if I have an account there, **even when I had previously logged out there**. But if I'm not logged in on 'stackexchange.com', I do not get logged in on that subdomain even if I am logged in on another subdomain. — The rationale behind this principle isn't very clear to me as I'm never on 'stackexchange.com' and have always perceived all SE domains as separate communities on the same level rather than in a hierarchy.

Comment: +sigh+ Scrap that, I'm now auto-logged in everywhere I have an account, if I log in to just one domain.

Comment: Previously, I wasn't auto-logged-in to other sites when I had third-party cookies disabled.  Not sure if that is still the case.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to create a whole new account (instead of linking your current network profile) to a new site.

*Join community* takes me to the right page (when I am logged in on other sites), but when I click *cancel*, there is no way to create a new account using another email address, or log in with an existing other email address.

Comment: [Relevant comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live#comment848288_260206).

Comment: If  you're already logged in, you need to log out in order to switch accounts or create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Does this change also affect the Stack Exchange Android app's login functionality?

Comment: No, it does not. Mobile apps authentication is completely separate.

Answer (score 1):

If a CAPTCHA system must be included, can it be ensured those of us with dyslexia & dysgraphia have alternative login authentications? Both the audio and character based CAPTCHAs defeat me. When I was last challenged on 20th April I was unable to pass.

Comment: Can you post this as a separate feature request please? Changing the captcha would be a huge change going well beyond the scope of the login project.

Answer (score 1):

Your new system doesn’t work at all for the first trilogy, I mean the older system worked with sites which are not a`stackexchange.com` subdomain, I need to log on each of them manually :[image]
[image][image]
The current site :[image]
This is the first time I’m happy that ᴀrea 51 is not concerned by a change, because the older system allowed auto‑log back when logged off on all sites :[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @AdamLear : ɪᴇ Opera presto ꜰꜰ and ɢɢ Chrome, so I don’t think it is relevant.

Comment: Are you still having issues?  It appears you have active sessions on all sites.  Just visit another trilogy site and you should still be logged in.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I also use the mobile app on android. But yes I still have the problem on web browsers. relogin never worked with the new system outside area 51. I could never get logged in automatically on the orginal trilogy.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas : And yes, I’m not logged in on the trilogy with the current computer.

Comment: I tested login on Opera version 12.02 and it works.  You will no longer see the dropdown after login, you should just be automatically logged in to all sites when you log in to one.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas : And for me, I still have the same problem. referer and JavaScript are enabled. Sorry about the delay for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I'm wondering if this will / has changed anything to do with the Private Beta login?

Comment: I don't think you should use answers to ask a new question.  Perhaps this would be more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: Not really. You'll still need to use the grant-beta-access URL that comes with invitations (or visit the A51 proposal after launch) to gain access to the site... Or such is the theory. We'll find out for realsies when we launch new sites tomorrow. ;)

Comment: Ooh #spoliers :P