# Can't log out of chat SE?

Tags: bug, chat, login, openid, logout

I just tried to log out of chat.SE (I'm an active user in GameDev and sometimes use other chat rooms), but I can't seem to. Could this possibly be tied to the new global-auth update?

I have tried hitting "log out" in the dropdown menu, which just redirects me to https://chat.stackexchange.com/logout. That link also does not work, just seemingly redirecting me to https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and showing my active rooms (aka the site rooms for GameDev.SE).

I can log out through the main GD.SE site proper, which also logs me out of chat, but upon clicking "log in" again on the chat site, I get: https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/authenticate. Logging in on the site proper seems to again, work as expected.

Some system information:
Windows 8.1
Browser: Firefox 39.0

Comment: Looking into this. Question: why are you explicitly logging out of chat?

Comment: I get a `Uncaught TypeError: StackExchange.ready is not a function` in the dev console. Repro-ed in Chrome win7

Comment: @AnnaLear It was more the intention to log out of SE completely, I was using chat at the time.

Comment: Maybe because of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live ?

Comment: @PythonMaster yeah, I think it is. I also mentioned it in my question IIRC :)

Comment: @Anna three months later, any updates? This was [reported again now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268016/unable-to-log-out-of-chat), maybe with some more details that can help debug it.