# Unable to log out of chat.

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, logout

I attempted to log out with the following actions:

[image]

This accomplished absolutely nothing since I remained logged in after clicking "log out" on the confirmation page. I then tried logging out of Stack Exchange from one of the network sites and repeated the steps above. The results were the same. I remained logged in no matter which combination of steps I performed.

In fact, the only way I could log out at all was to clear all of the cookies that were set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't log out of SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260362/cant-log-out-of-se)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that looks like a similar issue although the OP doesn't mention being logged in to chat again after logging out of SE.

Comment: Hmm... still most likely same root cause. Hope Anna will be back from SOinSD soon and take another look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fixed by Marc Gravell on 1-21-2016:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315174/logout-of-chat-stackoverflow-com-is-not-working/315189#315189)

> The "{chat}/logout" link shown pre-dated a few of our auth / universal-login changes, and was doomed to never work (we just identified you again and issued you with fresh chat cookies right away). We now link to the correct universal logout.