# "Thanks for the feedback" dialogue directs me to the old sign up page

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts

Sorry if this is a premature thing to note, but it relates to the [new login/signup system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live).

I was on a site where I didn't have an account, and absent mindedly clicked to upvote a post. It then popped up the sign in/create account dialogue

[image: Log in/sign up dialogue]

So I clicked sign up using Stack Exchange, assuming it's a one button click with the new system. But it actually brought me to the same old login/sign up page.

[image: Old sign up page]

If I click the "Join this Community" button at the top of the page it instead shows me just a button that I can click and automatically have the account created without re-adding my information. I don't even have the option of using the old sign up form, so this is hardly intentional is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently fixed. Now when you click to upvote on a site where you're not a member it only presents a single option "Join this community":

[image]

Clicking that brings you to a page where you can just click a button to confirm:

[image]