# "Thanks for the feedback" message seems badly-sized

Tags: bug, design

When I went to a site which I don't have an account on and tried to upvote an answer, I got the usual message, but looks like the text was recently updated, and the size of the popup wasn't changed to fit it nicely:

[image]

It used to be like this before:

[image]

---

Looks like it's like the top image when I'm logged in and it looks like the bottom image when I'm trying to do the same in private browsing mode.

Comment: No repro. I see what you posted in the "used to be like this" screenshot. What site? What browser? Try different browser or disabling all extensions/plugins/user scripts.

Comment: Looks like it's different across sites. Try a different site. I saw this [here](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/37473/how-can-you-tell-if-the-engine-is-not-brand-new).

Comment: What's odd is I see different messages while in normal mode (the first pic) and in private browsing mode (the second pic).

Comment: Still no repro, and assuming private mode disables all extensions (or maybe just user scripts?), it means it's most likely something on your side that you installed at some point, messing around with the font size.

Comment: Turned off everything, tried another browser installation, all reproduce this. It's not just me, if you search for other questions with "thanks for the feedback" message, you'll see [others also get this message look](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270514).

Comment: If you're logged in but don't have a profile on the site you're trying to vote on, you'll see the "join this community" message. (cc @ShadowWizard)

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Still this variant of the popup looks kinda bad, which my bug report is about.

Comment: @Adam I know, but the issue here is the font size/family of the title, not the different text.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't disagree, just explaining what seems to be your repro issue? You just said you saw the "used to be like this" screenshot, which shows a fully anonymous view.

Comment: @Adam sorry, I meant I see the title with the non-bold font as in second screenshot.