# Too much whitespace in "Thanks for the feedback"

Tags: bug, design, post-feedback

While attempting to downvote something on a site I don't have an account on, I see this message, which has too much whitespace:

[image]

The same thing happens with upvotes (and プラス票が):

[image][image]

(I think it's safe to say that this is a network-wide bug, since I took these all on different sites.)

However, it looks more reasonable when you are not logged into the network at all (e.g. in private browsing):

[image]

An earlier version of this issue was reported at ["Thanks for the feedback" message seems badly-sized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285977/323179), but the difference is that there is no newsletter UI on the right anymore. (The extra space could have been justified before given the height of the newsletter; now it's definitely a bug.)

Also, is newsletter supposed to be gone?