# 2017 TeamDAG project updates

Tags: feature-request, announcements

- [Who is TeamDAG?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth)
- What is the TeamDAG working on?
- Why are you working on that and not [insert favorite feature request here].

These are some of the questions that we hear regularly on meta.so and meta.se. In an attempt to answer them, we are kicking off regular updates from the DAG team. These updates will provide a quick overview of the work we have done in the last several weeks and will list some of the notable work that we will/are working on or planning. Over time, they will morph and change being that they are plans, so nothing is guaranteed. That said, we hope you find these updates informative.

#### [December 2017 update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304122/354333)

#### [November 2017 update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302969/354333)

#### [October 2017 update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301450/354333)

Comment: Any chance you could add an explanation, or a link to an explanation, of how the priorities of "TeamDAG" are set/how you decide what to work on?

Comment: Bit of mess here now. Is this coming instead of [What features did the Community Team discuss, have implemented, or have denied last month?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291031/152859)? In addition to it?

Comment: Also, glad to see you can add moderator tags now, even without a diamond! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - this is in addition to the CR work that JNat posts. That is even linked in the answer...

Comment: @Oded still, confusing. No way to merge them nicely under one "roof"? :)

Comment: I'm not sure why we try to close vote this, specially for the reason *does not appear to seek input and discussion*.

Comment: @rene well, question lacked [tag:announcements] tag which should make it clear it's indeed an announcement, not seeking input. And since only SE staff can really "answer" it, even if it gets closed, there will be no real impact.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sorry for the confusion with the CR process. I'll think about how to address that more fully, but hopefully this simple description helps. For us the two are very different. TeamDAG is a product team and our work is guided by a vision and strategy for building our business and serving our customers. The CR process is a method for injecting some specific types of improvements that may not get considered based on vision/strategy. We attempt to take care of a few of those each month.

Comment: Also, the scope and scale of work items that we consider for CRs are quite small in general. They are a day or few of work in most cases. While some of the things below will take one or two devs days, weeks or more to do.

Comment: @hamlet I'll work on a post to help explain how we set our priorities. It probably won't come until next week.

Comment: @Joe thanks. You mentioned "serving our customers" - who are those customers? The Community Team members like Tim Post or Shog9? Or do you mean us, the users?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, in some ways the Community Team could be considered our customers too, but I was really talking about members and users of the sites.

Comment: Team DAG is an anagram for "Data Gem". I'm just sayin'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## December 2017

### Done

**[Revised question page hero](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359708/new-sign-up-hero-for-question-pages):** We've updated the sign up banner that anonymous users see on all question pages. It is now a more subtle bar at the bottom of the window. There was a bunch of on point criticism of the prior version as being too big, too annoying and obscuring the most important content.

**Grace period for sign up notifications:** We've added a new feature that sets a global "grace period" of 24 hours that prevents dismissible sign-up notifications across a single site. That means if you dismiss the new blue banner at the bottom, you won't see similar notifications for another 24 hours even if we update the notification.

**[Ask a question template](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360261/7782017):** We launched an AaQ template experiment on 12/1/2017.

**Top Bar:** Live on [SE.com](https://stackexchange.com). Oh, and we [updated the review queue icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359943/new-reviews-icon). Hope you think it's an improvement.

**Dev survey support:** The annual dev survey is coming in the new year. The team wrapped up our work to provide a better experience for signed in users and to ensure that badges are awarded to all who want them.

---

### In progress

**Navigation improvements:** We are committed to improvements to our site information architecture to support [Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358943/what-s-happening-with-channels?) and generally create a more scalable IA that will support other new features. These changes are in progress and others continue to be investigated for the future. User research is ongoing. If you are interested in a chance to participate in this or future research, make sure you opt into user research via your email settings. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cdAf.png)

**Response to top bar feedback:** There are a number of things in the works from the volumunous community feedback. You will be seeing additional updates this month.

**Review Queue Indicator improvements:** Again, working on improvements based on community feedback. Going a bit slower than planned, but we hope to see updates this month. If you haven't seen [this post on how the RQI works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly), then check it out.

**[Hats for Winter Bash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/):** Hat making is well underway. The finest milliners are on the case to make sure we have enough hats for everybody. Expect to see a best in class headgear collection.

---

### Starting in December

*Each of the items below describes some work that is planned for the coming month. As needed, we will directly engage the community to help shape the work.*

**Tag subscriptions:** We recently rolled out an improved tag subscription experience optimized for our [Enterprise product](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise). We are looking into bringing this to our public Q&A sites, how it will work with Channels and how to combine it with the [Filtered questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) functionality on Stack Exchange.

**Channels features:** TeamDAG is working on a variety of features related for our Channels product. This includes ask a question experience, optimizations for question list views, channel newsletters, and a long list of other  enhancements that will make Channels work well.

---

### Investigations

*The work described here is in the very earliest stages. As these items progress, we will engage with the community to gather feedback, use cases and other insights to inform the work. But it is always possible that nothing will come of this work.*

**Responsive design:** We are in the early stages of this investigation. (Check out [what is responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)) There is an amazing amount of work required to do this right and it's easy to break things. We've started with an MVP that is looking pretty cool, but we still have a long way to go. This effort is connected to our navigation improvements and channels work.

**Site theme standardization:** As we look at navigation improvements and responsive design, we are beginning to realize that our current theming support for some graduated network sites creates a lot of fragility. While most sites have limited theming, a few sites are extensively themed. We will catalogue which elements are currently customized on each site and investigate some options for standardizing site theme support. After we've completed this discovery step, we will gather feedback from the community. We want to continue supporting individual site themes, but we need to pare down what can be customized so that Stack Exchange sites can benefit from Stack Overflow design improvements.

---

### Postponed

**Ask a question wizard:** We've done some concept designs, but are putting this on hold until we have results from our template experiment (see above).

**Community requests:** JNat keeps track of our progress on these [via this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l). No progress in November nor is much likely in December due to holidays and channels work.

Answer (score 58):

## October 2017

*Note: I updated the title here to match the timing of reports going forward.*

### Done

**Mentorship experiment:** The experiment is over and we learned a ton. More details are coming in a post from the team tomorrow. [For background on the experiment checkout this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project).

**Review queue updates:**  We’ve rolled [the red review dot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red) out to everyone on SO and it will come to the entire network with the topbar.  These UX changes have improved the flow of reviews. We will continue to keep our eye on this area, but there are no further changes planned.

**“New feature” notification:** This experiment is done and the notification is ready to be used for future new features.  You won’t see this notification a lot, but hopefully you’ll be excited to see it when it appears. [See the post for more details.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification)

**Inline sign up:** Thanks to our move to https, we implemented inline sign up on our homepage a couple months ago. This change makes signing up for an account easier and it makes it clear you can reuse your Google or Facebook accounts to sign up. We’ve now added [inline sign up to the hero banner on question pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4UG9.jpg). This took a bit longer due to performance concerns since question pages are responsible for almost all of the sites page views.

---

### In progress

**Rolling out new Top Bar for the network sites:** We turned on a version of the new top bar for meta.stackexchange.com and for all mods on their site. We are [working through a wide array of feedback from the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network) and plan to release the top bar  for all network sites in October.

---

### Starting in October

Each of the items below describe some work that is planned for the coming month. As needed, we will directly engage the community to help shape the work.

**Automating success measures for question quality:** One of the things we learned from the mentorship experiment is that our current experimentation system doesn’t work for question quality experiments. First step to make progress in this area is to automate what it takes to validate success/failure of any experiment. Not sexy, but critical for us to move quicker.

**Ask a question template:** This idea is an oldie, but a goodie. [See this post as an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231827/revisiting-question-templates). We think this is a simple place to start on question quality.

**Announcement banner:** We are redesigning the announcement banner for system alerts (e.g. site is in read only mode due to fail over) and targeted user messages (e.g “we need you to update your email address”). This is part of the [user messaging system mentioned in the new feature notification post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification).

**Community team requests:** Jnat keeps track of our progress on these [via this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l). Each month we try to take on a few items championed by the community team.

---

### Investigating

**Ask a question wizard** Several people have proposed breaking down the “ask a question” experience into steps. We are going to start investigations on this in October.

**Draft post:** One of the most interesting findings from the mentorship experiment was around the value of being able to create and share draft questions. We think this feature is worth exploring and we will be starting an investigation in October.

Comment: Is "new feature notification" specific to SO or network-wide?  SO's topbar is taller (which seems to matter for the current "new" grapheme) and you linked to a post on MSO, which is why I ask.  Also, is the announcement banner system-wide or just on SO?  (It sounds like it should be system-wide.)

Comment: I'm very happy to hear about the exploration of question quality (templates or wizards).  And shared drafts sound like they would address the need filled by sandboxes on some sites.  (You might want to look at how those are being used, if you're not already.)

Comment: "Question templates" seem like a great idea. Particularly so of it can be customized at tag level - like tag wiki. Maybe let the experts decide the structure of the question (for given tag) so that you don't have to make a "one size fits all" template. I know that the author of original post mentions strictly against it, but I see plenty of questions in JavaScript, where the OP forgets to post HTML; or in SQL, where they forget to post table structure. It would make everyone's life easier if they can see those placeholders in the template.

Comment: @MonicaCellio New feature notification, announcement banner and any other part of the user messaging system will be used network-wide when appropriate. We will ensure it works across all sites.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yep, sandboxes is a great use case for draft notes.

Comment: @NisargShah We will likely start at site level templates but it is possible the idea could expand to something more sophisticated.

Comment: _“New feature” notification: This experiment is done and the notification is ready to be used for future new features._ Well played for brushing the [negative feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification) under the carpet. _"Yeah, we got loads of clicks... and really positive feedback on Meta.. wait.. what?!"_

Comment: I really like the idea of being able to create question drafts.

Comment: I think the wizard idea is lousy whomever suggested it should be burniated!  Please don't do this, I am not booking a car, flight, and hotel I'm only asking a question.

Comment: @tanner Actually I linked directly to the post with the negative feedback where I responded to some of the feedback last night. So, no, I'm not brushing it under the carpet. We have millions of signed in users coming to the site every week and over a hundred thousand of them took advantage of the notification. Many more dismissed it, which we are making even easier. The team believes this strikes the best balance between completing goals.

Comment: @JonH Everything around question quality will be extensively tested. If it doesn't produce the right results, then we will try to improve it and test again or drop it. Also, some of these ideas for ask a question could be primarily targeted at new users who've never or infrequently asked a question.

Comment: @JoeFriend I was talking generally about the fact that 75% (vote wise) of meta users didn't like the NFN, and it went ahead anyway. Cody's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification#comment518009_356853) sums up how I feel if I'm honest.

Comment: @JonH the wizard thing is good on some sites though. On Stack Overflow one can identify several categories of questions, where each category would have a distinct structure, and therefore a question template. However, what is needed is some kind of step through for a new user to guide in what kind of form they should present their question.

Comment: @JoeFriend I have had the notion for a while to create a feature request for the Ask A Question page. Would it be worth fleshing this out (with an interactive demo) and posting it as a feature request, or does the team have a pretty clear-cut implementation already designed and planned? My thought is a mix between a template and a 'lite' question wizard.

Comment: As long as you’re messing with the “Sign Up” interface, would you consider adding something to it to make it abundantly clear that “Sign Up” means *create a new account*? We’ve have problems with people who, despite seeing a “Sign Up” button right next to a “Log In” button, think “Sign Up” = “Sign In” = the thing to do to get signed in to your existing account. Maybe something simple, like a question “Do you already have an account on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, or any other Stack Exchange network site?” and, if the person doesn’t answer “No”, then refuse to create a new account.

Comment: @TylerH We are just starting our investigations and design sprint in October. We'd love to see your ideas in whatever form.

Comment: @G-Man If they use their correct credentials then the sign up form will work for sign in. And, I believe it works visa versa. Are they creating additional accounts with new credentials?

Comment: @G-Man Perhaps replace "Sign Up" with "Create Account"...

Comment: @TylerH: That would probably help a lot.

Comment: @G-Man The phrase is a bit longer, which can always create problems (particularly in other languages). That said, I'm not sure I understand what we are trying to avoid. Can you clarify?

Comment: @JoeFriend:  We are trying to avoid having [people like this one](https://meta.superuser.com/q/10764/354511) try to sign in to Stack Exchange with an existing Stack Exchange account by going to the “Sign Up” page.  Or [this person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260926/271976) who couldn't figure out that, when you *have* an account, you should “Log In” to it, and not “Sign Up” again.  These are just two examples I was able to find; I think I’ve seen others.  If only six to eight users have made this error in the history of Stack Exchange, then maybe we don’t need to coddle them.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  P.S. Is there a good reason to move “Sign Up” to the right of “Log In”, when they’re currently in the other order?

Comment: @G-Man Those examples are fairly old, and the second issue was fixed. The signup page was also simplified to only ask for the password once, and if the email/password (or Google/FB credential) matches an existing account, we fall back to the login flow like Joe said. Keep in mind that those views (and the "join community" thing) were brand new in 2015 and a change from how login/signup used to work before [universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153). I can see how there would be some confusion, but unless it's ongoing and current... those were likely just temporal support issues.

Comment: Is there a reason we can't use Meta for draft questions? Code Golf has the Sandbox, for instance. I think World Building has something similar, but I might be wrong. Do we really need to spend time building something?

Comment: When reviewing question quality, please also take into consideration the effect on answerers. If questions eventually end up following the same boring format (or even worse feel like the user filled out a questionary through a wizard), then I’m a lot less likely to care about those questions.

Comment: For the "ask a question wizard", try saving the title for *after* the user asks their question. I think the process of asking the question solidifies your issue in a way that allows you to easily summarize it. To summarize it before you asked is much harder.

Comment: @poke That's a good point, but in many cases, questions *should* follow a general format. The format for the question "Why isn't my code working" should pretty much always be "I'm trying to do X. Here are my constraints. Here's my MCVE. Here's any extraneous info about what else I've thought of. What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Another benefit of [@Won't’s suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301449/271976#comment980464_301450) is that it will discourage users from using the title as the first sentence of their question, and encourage them to use it as a descriptive summary of the entire question.

Comment: I don't know if the suggestions by Won't or G-Man will work as they predict but I hope they would.  My wish: that people would write titles that look decent when the question is tweeted. Anything the wizard can do that would encourage descriptive summaries instead of long rambling strings for question titles would be fine by me.

Comment: @Stijn An update will be coming out this week.

Answer (score 12):

## November 2017

### Done

**Upgraded Elasticsearch engine:** Thanks to the architecture team, we are now running the latest version of Elasticsearch. This provides a foundation for future search improvements. Our plan is to provide ongoing enhancements to search accuracy and relevance in the coming months. In addition to improving site search, we are interested in an experiment to help first time question askers find existing answers to their question in an effort to avoid duplicates.

**Automating success measures for question quality:** We now have an automated method to validate success/failure of any Ask a Question experiments. We call this a "Question Grade". Jon Ericson posted [details on this work so you can understand our approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests). I can't emphasize how critical this is for us to move forward on the question quality effort. Also, a side benefit is that this provides us an important health indicator for Q&A as well.

**Top Bar for network sites:** This is live for all Q&A sites and will be coming this week to [SE.com](https://stackexchange.com). Chat and Area 51 are coming soon. See below for additional work we will be doing in this area.

**New feature notification improvements:** We enhanced the dismiss logic of the New Feature Notification and put in a delay so that it doesn't pop up on your first page view. We also improved dismiss for the sign up hero. We will be combining the two approaches so that all of our user messaging (NFN, hero, announcement banner, etc) use a consistent dismiss logic that is reliable and predictable.

---

### In progress

**Ask a question template:** Now that we have our automated method for measuring question quality improvements, we can move forward with an AaQ template experiment. See [the team's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions) for community feedback on this idea.

**Announcement banner:** We are redesigning the announcement banner for system alerts (e.g. “site is in read only mode due to fail over”) and targeted user messages (e.g “we need you to update your email address”). This is part of the [user messaging system mentioned in the new feature notification post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification).

**Community requests:** JNat keeps track of our progress on these [via this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l). Each month we try to take on a few items championed by the community team. Sadly, we only got part way through one CR this month. We hope to bang out several in November.

---

### Starting in November

*Each of the items below describes some work that is planned for the coming month. As needed, we will directly engage the community to help shape the work.*

**Revised question page hero:** We pushed a new (really big) sign up hero for anonymous users on stackoverflow.com. Did I mention it was really big? Well, the MSO community took us to task. We were wrong, the community was right. See [my full mea culpa here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359008/7782017). We will be testing a couple of smaller designs that we hope will still encourage people to sign up without taking over their screens. Our goal is to test these designs and push one of them live before the end of the month.

**Ask a question wizard:** We have some designs for the community to give feedback on and will be posting the ideas soon. If all goes well with the first question quality experiment (see above), then we may run an experiment this month.

**Response to top bar feedback:** There are a number of things we plan to address this month from the volumunous community feedback. Details and responses to all feedback on the top bar will be posted this week.

**Review Queue Indicator improvements:** This is another area where we've received some great feedback. We will be addressing issues that will make this work better for users who don't have access to all the queues and for users of lower volume sites. If you haven't seen [this post on how the RQI works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly), then check it out.

**Dev survey support:** The annual dev survey is coming soon. The team is providing support to provide a better experience for signed in users and to ensure that badges are awarded to all who want them.

---

### Investigating

*The work described here is in the very earliest stages. As these items progress, we will engage with the community to gather feedback, use cases and other insights to inform the work. But it is always possible that nothing will come of this work.*

**Information Architecture investigation:** We are considering improvements to our site Information Architecture to support [Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358943/what-s-happening-with-channels?) and generally create a more scalable IA that will support other new features. We've made various changes to our navigation over the years, but it has been a while since we've stepped back and look at how the various parts of the site interact. This project will start looking at the site as a whole, frequently used parts/pages and continue looking at individual pages that haven't been touched in years and need some TLC.

**Tag subscriptions:** We recently rolled out an improved tag subscription experience optimized for our [Enterprise product](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise). We are looking into bringing this to our public Q&A sites, how it will work with Channels and how to combine it with the [Filtered questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) functionality on Stack Exchange.

---

### Postponed

**Draft post:** We are still excited about this concept that we tested as a part of the mentorship experiment, but it is taking a bit of a back seat to some of the channels work. I'm hoping we can come back to this early next year.

Comment: Re the new top bar on SE.com: [please keep notifications visible on phones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301923/162102)!  I don't care if you do that by making a mobile version or moving things around, but userscripting isn't a tool in the mobile toolbox.

Comment: @MonicaCellio who said that you can't use userscripts on mobile? :) Firefox on Android supports extensions, and through some black magic you can import userscripts into Greasemonkey

Comment: @angussidney Greasemonkey/Firefox and Tampermonkey/Chrome on my Android tablet both either didn't install or didn't work (been a while, don't remember how each failed).  I don't see a way to install Tampermonkey in Chrome on my phone, and am not interested in a completely separate browser (which I gather is what the TM *app* is).  If there's an easy solution that doesn't require *me* to conjure black magic, I'd welcome a link!