# How is question quality measured in A/B tests?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, testing

As sites grow, there's a noticeable increase in community unhappiness with question quality. Quite a bit of the problem is simply a matter of scale, but sites sometimes [optimize for extremes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438). Bad askers don't notice or care that their questions are bad and potential good askers tend to be more sensitive to criticism. A dangerous feedback cycle sets in where members of the site are rightly critical of new questions which discourages potentially good askers from asking which leaves a greater percentage of bad questions remaining.

We've heard [lots of suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=question%20quality) and we'd like to [start testing some of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions). But in order to do that, we need an objective measure of question quality. Or rather, we need an objective measure of *the community perception of question quality*, which is thankfully easier to obtain. As [Clay Shirky says](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html):

> So the group is real. It will exhibit emergent effects. It can't be ignored, and it can't be programmed, which means you have an ongoing issue. And the best pattern, or at least the pattern that's worked the most often, is to put into the hands of the group itself the responsibility for defining what value is, and defending that value, rather than trying to ascribe those things in the software upfront.

Taking that to heart, we've defined a simple "question grade" based on objective measures of community feedback:

- **Good**

  ```
    (Score > 0 or (AnswerCount > 0 and Score = 0)) and !Closed
  ```
- **Bad**

  ```
    Score < 0 or Closed
  ```
- **Neutral**

  ```
     Score = 0 and !Closed and AnswerCount = 0
  ```

In all cases, *Closed excludes duplicate closures* because [not all duplicates are bad for the site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). Duplicate questions are a big part of community frustration, so it feels weird to ignore them. Fortunately, unhelpful duplicates tend to be downvoted as well as closed. When we run tests of features specifically designed to reduce duplicates (such as search improvements), we'll use a metric that takes duplicate closure into account.

Accepted answers aren't useful in this case since we are measuring the community's assessment rather than asker's. This is also a potential reason for excluding duplicate closures as [askers have a say in that case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes).

36% of deletions within the first three days of a questions life are executed by the asker. Beyond that time, [most deletions are automatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion) and intended to remove cruft and not necessarily because questions are bad. We considered counting just community-initiated deletions, but that made question grade calculations noticeably more expensive to calculate. Fortunately, most deleted questions are downvoted or closed, so statistically speaking, deletion adds very little signal.

Finally, the grade is calculated after 3 days. Our data team discovered that on Stack Overflow:

> - 18.5% of posts never change their status: that is, they’re permanently neutral.
> - 67.6% of posts have “solidified” their status in the first hour.
> - 91.6% solidify within 3 days.

[image: Solidified quality]

For the purpose of question quality A/B tests, we're going to consider neutral questions as equivalent to bad questions. Since that divides questions roughly in half on Stack Overflow, tests will resolve more quickly. Our data team also reports that using this criteria, 73% of questions solidify into their good/not-good category *within an hour*.

## Validation of question grades

For the purposes of A/B testing, we need a measure that quickly categorizes all questions. There are certainly going to be edge cases, such as boring questions that happen to get amazing answers or decent questions that are ignored for some reason. To quote [Carveth Read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carveth_Read):

> It is better to be vaguely right than exactly wrong.

This very simple grading of questions matches the intuition most of us have that as a percentage of all questions, fewer of them are good or even answerable. Look no further than the steady decline of good questions on Stack Overflow:

[image: Percentage of asked questions by grade on Stack Overflow]

You can even spot the [noticeable dip of 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320223/what-happened-to-stack-overflow-in-2014) which coincided with the observation that [Stack Overflow had become particularly negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late). So while this metric is not perfect, it is simple and seems to accurately track the community's evaluation of new questions as they come in. When tackling technical solutions to question quality, we can be confident we're on the right track if there's a statistically meaningful increase in "good" questions as defined above.

If you are interested in how other communities have evaluated their questions over time, you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/edit/747684#graph) in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial). There's a very obvious trend of decreasing question grade as sites grow. While our current focus is on Stack Overflow because of its scale and importance to our business, the testing we do there will be useful for all other Stack Exchange sites that grow large enough. That will likely include [sites customers pay for](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise). Whether your site has a question quality problem now or will in the future, we'd like to verify that changes we make a positive difference.

Comment: is "answers" in your formulas number of answers, or scores of answers, or what?

Comment: "You can even spot the noticeable dip of 2014 which conincided with the observation that Stack Overflow had become particularly negative." People have been posting questions on meta complaining about negativity constantly since it was created.  If there was a dip at any point in time you could find a meta post for that same time period complaining about negativity.

Comment: Most are not quite so heavily referenced, @servy. The big event there wasn't the post, it was several months of plummeting quality, commemorated in several well-known meta threads.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry. Answer count. If a question hasn't been voted up or down, but does have an answer, it's "good" in this system. So many questions are not voted on at all, we needed some other signal. It's not perfect (someone might drop a joke answer that gets downvoted, for instance), but it better than just using question score.

Comment: @JonEricson Would using positively scored answers instead of just "has answers" be feasible?

Comment: @Servy Certainly possible, but not sure it is important. It's worth noting that we erred on keeping this as simple as possible.

Comment: How is a question that has an answer but has no votes itself good?  A question that isn’t considered to be helpful by the community but answered doesn’t seem all that amazing to me.  What other types of questions are considered good?

Comment: @Ramhound: We aren't talking "amazing" just good enough to be answered and not get downvoted. Remember that question downvotes are free, so there's not reason not to do that if the question is bad. We're trying to get some signal from the [huge number of questions that aren't voted on at all](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/754440#graph).

Comment: Have you considered plotting the question quality not as a function of time, but as a function of total amount of questions? That might make comparison of various sites easier and more fair (especially considering various growth rates, since time is removed from the equation). It might also shed light on optimal size of sites, thresholds for certain actions/campains, etc, especially if the trend is not linear and if it turns out to be similar for all sites. Just my $0.02.

Comment: While you said you want to keep this measure simple, wouldn't you want `Score = 0 and AnswerCount = 1 and SelfAnswered` to fall into the Neutral bucket? That's a question that no-one else has done anything positive with.

Comment: This trend could also be attributed to quality expectations increasing vastly as SO has grown. No more 800-score questions asking to convince the asker that PHP is good, for example.

Comment: Are deleted questions included in the quality/time graph? Bad questions may be deleted the longer they hang around, no?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, deleted questions are included in [the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/747684#graph). Bad questions are, indeed, likely to get deleted.

Comment: Which analysis? The template results? At any rate, [here's the graph of how many first votes came at each year interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgsp8.png) for questions. I'm not sure where the 5 votes at 10 years comes from, but I'm guessing it's rounding? When you add in answering (not shown) there just aren't many questions that switch from neutral to good years down the line. 3 days captures most of the signal and is a lot more practical than waiting several years to evaluate an experiment. ;-)

Comment: For "good" questions the *logic table* you are using says: "any closed question is not a good question, regardless of the number of upvotes or answers" ***but*** isn't that a factor in the *unwelcoming complaints*, one *must* ask on the proper site. A newcomer should have asked on a different one of the several computer related sites instead, so it's closed, bye bye. It seems easy to get kicked out of the *good* category and be excluded from the neutral or bad, entering limbo. Be entirely forgotten and you are *promoted* to "Neutral". Getting to "bad" has two avenues, one way is even drive-by.

Comment: I'm by no means *good* at SQL but I [edited the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/993448/historical-question-grades-by-week-add-any-good-answer-even-closed#graph) to show (so-called) "OK" questions, ones that may or may not have been deleted but obtained upvotes. It seems like there's a couple of significant bumps, Oct 2012 and Apr 2015, where closed questions scored well. Perhaps those were the *ask anywhere* (presumably a *close guess*) group of well formulated questions that were ultimately (but not initially) rejected; causing ill will, and the occasional blog.

Comment: @Rob: I wouldn't think of "Neutral" as definitive state. Instead, we don't have any signal to know if the question is good or not. _Most_ close votes are definitive signals that the question is just not helpful on any site. Even so, the difference between including it and not is marginal as your query shows. We include it because the primary purpose of this metric is to help us figure out if changes are going to result in more questions the community is interested in answering. If we build a feature that helps people find the right site to ask, this metric will help with that too.

Comment: @JonEricson Perhaps a more effective route would be to collect the data and perform an initial analysis as you have done, then ask on [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) if someone sees a method to glean some additional information or any improvements. As to finding the correct site for people, perhaps [Gutenberg](https://github.com/SOBotics/Guttenberg) could be modified to look for similar questions (and tags) and suggest to users (with the " New contributor" banner) that they should consider if their question is a better fit on another site, and have a 'Site Review Queue' for new

Comment: I probably have more positively received questions on this network than **ANY** other user. And the site actively discourages me all the time. Not a single SO Employee has ever sought my well informed opinions on this network, and I could tell you exactly where your problems are and who's at fault for them. And, I could provide examples.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I already know [who to blame](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311933/1438).

Comment: I wouldn't blame the ignorant kids at the bottom when you could easily point to fascists at the top. I haven't ever withheld a good question because of the masses of stupid users you've accrued. However, I actually stopped using Ask Ubuntu, StackOverflow, and SuperUser because your admins there are demonstrably incompetent (and we have no tools to keep them in check).

Comment: @JonEricson Would you mind to update these graphs with up to 2020 data?

Comment: @wim: I'm no longer an employee, so I don't have access to the R script that generated the first graph. You can see [the second graph with public data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/747684/historical-question-grades-by-week#graph). Looks level since 2018 or so. (Not sure if internal data would show something different. Probably best to leave the existing graph.)