# How long will Strangeworks sponsor the Quantum Computing site?

Tags: discussion, advertising, blog, sponsored-sites

I read [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/27/quantum-computing-site-launches-with-the-help-of-strangeworks/?cb=1) about [quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Per [Robert Cartaino♦ comment reply in this Q&A about sponsorship generally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307861/295854)

> @benisuǝqbackwards Since this is being administered as a marketing/ads
>   program, it depends on the agreement reached, but the site itself
>   would persist either way under our normal site workflow whether the
>   sponsorship continued or not.

How long will Strangeworks be sponsoring the site?

Comment: This question belongs at the [quantumcomputing meta site.](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it belongs to the login page of  quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I assume https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com is the link you meant to post. It either doesn't exist or is only for users with accounts, so it redirects to that page.

Comment: It does exist, just create your account here and ask the question :)

Comment: @nicael I prefer that the answer be somewhere publicly available.

Comment: Considering that this is about sponsorship, it seems like a reasonable question for here, particularly if there may be a general answer such as "sponsorships start at six month durations with the option to extend".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Stack Exchange sponsorships have a 12-month commitment. Specific agreements could be different, but that is how they are generally structured at this time.

Comment: Ha! So I was off by half... thanks for the info!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you include a source?

Comment: If you look at his [linkedin account](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/joseph-lippens/10/512/244), he works in sales at SE, @Goose :)

Comment: You can also [use the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/271350?site=meta&filter=!%29RwcIFZvM1wfrdmfZFL6T7hi) to see that `is_employee` is set to `true` on his account.