# Are Stack Exchange 1.0 Sites still available for creation?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, stackexchange-2.0

Can you still get the software to make a 1.0 site in return for a payment?
I would assume they remove the method after switching to 2.0.
But I was wondering if it's still a method that is an alternative to Area 51.

Comment: @James it has been edited.

Comment: It's not just been edited, you've entirely changed the question :(

Comment: @James It's Better than making 10 separate questions!

Comment: I voted to close as your first one was a dupe, now it's not  a dupe. As such I had to retract my vote and cannot vote to close for a reason to suit your "new" question. Which is why changing questions is not ideal , it breaks the functions, and also wastes people's time. Also, what is "10 separate questions"? You had 1, now you have another 1. That's 2 questions.

Comment: Right in the dupe's answer: "We stopped providing the software in exchange for payment and started using the Area 51 process to create new sites instead." How much plainer does it need to be?

Comment: @muru I understand now.

Comment: @James I will have more questions after this so it will probably end up being 4 or 5 questions. 10 is a common number people use to represent "several" or "a lot". It was obviously an exaggeration.

Comment: The answer is in the blog post linked in the answer to the duplicate target.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I obviously know what the answer is at this point since https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek answered me. the blog post does not in fact give a clear and reasonable explanation to my question. i say this is not a duplicate of the other question users have linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE 1.0 is dead. Long live [SO Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise). More or less its the way to run your own Stack Overflow Instance, with all the new shiny stuff like teams.

You'd need to talk to sales for exact pricing.

If you want to push a public site along - you might be able to convince SE to let you [sponsor a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/sponsorship-pilot-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange)

Comment: Thanks Journeyman Geek!