# How can a site get sponsored tags?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, advertising, community, sponsored-tags

There has been quite a bit of chatter recently on Stack Exchange's priorities with respect to the sites, specifically on how Stack Overflow and technical sites are seen as the primary revenue streams.

In response to that discussion, I made a [proposal](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12821/70477) on Science Fiction and Fantasy.SE's Meta proposing that the site allow sponsored tags as a way to prove its value to the company in a way that might only be non-disruptive to the community, but potentially interesting or even fun.

How does a community, especially a non-technical one, actually go about getting tag sponsorships?

- Is this community-driven, where the site will be updated to allow tag sponsorships if and only if the community clearly establishes a consensus that it wants them?
- Is it necessary to have potential tag sponsors already in line and expressing clear interest before the technical changes can be made?

To be clear, I'm not asking what tag sponsorships *are*, nor am I asking how to sponsor a tag on Stack Overflow. I'm asking how sites that don't currently have sponsored tags go about getting them.

Comment: You’d have to make an economic argument, with the hypothetical audience being companies who we’d be asking to pay to sponsor tags. That economic argument will almost certainly hinge on visitor counts (and derived “impressions”), which is much easier on huge sites like SO than it is on small sites like SF&F. In other words, I think the issue with this request is cart-and-horse. The real way to show the company the value of small sites is to *grow them into big sites*.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange

Comment: @rene that is about *site* sponsorships, not *tag* sponsorships.

Comment: Just curious... do you understand what a sponsored tag is? Do you have someone at Tor or Disney looking to pay for a sponsorship?

Comment: @Catija I do know what a sponsored tag is. I don't have anyone right now who is clearly interested. My question could be interpreted as whether it is potentially even worth it to *look* for potential tag sponsors, or if Stack Exchange the company is just going to say "no" or "that's not enough, you need at least 20 different sponsors sponsoring a total of 100 different tags for it to be worth our while to implement this". Maybe I don't know anyone at Disney. Maybe I *do*, but I am hesitant to approach them with a proposal until I know what the conditions would be. What are they?

Comment: Contact Advertising. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277946/3648282  https://stackoverflow.com/advertising#advertising  https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines --- minimum spend U$10K/month.