# Left nav is now sticky

Tags: discussion, left-nav

We've updated the left nav so that it is now sticky. We are planning to add this ability to scroll the left nav independently, but that will be added later since it shouldn't be needed by anyone currently. As we extend the use of the left nav it will become required.

Comment: I have my top bar configured as non sticky as I generally don't like (hate, if you need stronger words) screen elements that follow me around while I'm scrolling through a page. I would have expected the left nav would honor the preference I have set for my topbar. Or can I also read *scroll the left nav independently* as don't scroll at all.

Comment: Leave it to Safari to require a prefixed property for this... -_- This is good news, though; one property I can remove from my Stylish CSS script

Comment: @rene Typically you *want* site navigational links to be visible without having to *go somewhere to find them*... including scrolling. Even many sites that have the scrolling problem apply a bandaid with a "back to top" link that follows you or is available at most anchors on a page.

Comment: @TylerH I'm fine with being  a-typical ...

Comment: Quick question. Why can't we bring back the same good ol' styles back to Stack Overflow please? That was too better considering the current change. I need to click twice to click on tags / users / jobs and no idea where did badges go... `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think that was covered during the previous round of top bar changes while you were perhaps on leave from SO

Comment: @TylerH `:(` Link me there, please? Is it any time considered? Reverting back to old one?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think there's any plan to move back to the old one - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes or earlier is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It seems like something that they aren't willing to support. And that makes sense to me. One of the major benefits of changing the layout is that it reduces the number of site versions that need to exist. Once they optimize for mobile, they don't need the mobile version any more. And all of the sites will be (more or less) on the same code base so updates are simple and clean. Keeping the "retro" style around makes a lot more work for them.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yep, I would encourage you to read the post linked above to understand the reasons for the left nav and other changes. These are critical to enable us to move the site forward and provide additional space to expose on new features. Not just Teams, but other core Q&A features too.

Comment: @rene left nav and top bar shouldn't use the same preference.  The left nav consumes that width from my screen no matter what I do, so I might as well have stuff in it.  The top bar, on the other hand, only consumes that space at the top, unless I want it to be sticky.  It's reasonable to therefore want a sticky left nav and a non-sticky top bar.  (Assuming you're using the left nav, I mean; obviously you can banish it entirely.)

Comment: Fantastic thanks :) I get why some people don't take to the new things, we all have different opinions, but also I think people should give these things some time to get used to them. We're all so used to Stack being set in it's way that change can be a shock.

Comment: @James You made me smile, just as I head out for my weekend.