# Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information, then what?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Is it intended to hide the extended instructive text? It isn't visible at all now because when you enter something, it disappears.

[image: la la la]

[image: la la la]

Comment: it also hides the comment you are typing, which is really annoying

Comment: Seems to be a browser dependant issue since it does not occur in the StackExchange Android app. It does occur in Firefox 61.0 on Android 4.4.2 (Kitkat)

Comment: Also on Android 8 and latest Chrome. Jess, who is still using Android 4 in 2018...

Comment: Reproducible on iOS 11.1.1 Safari (though I can scroll the default text in the text box to read the next line if I don't type anything).

Comment: For me (Firefox on Android), it’s not even a complete line. I can’t tell, e.g., whether I have typed a comma or a period.

Comment: Using Firefox for Android, version 62.0b7, in desktop mode I can read both sentences. In mobile mode the second sentence's descenders are cut off; so it says: "Avoid answerinα αuestions in"

Comment: Does not occur for me. FF 58 on Debian.

Comment: @Tensibai Nope.

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant then, as the report target the mobile version of the sites (per its tag).

Comment: @klutt: Note the [tag:mobile-web] tag.

Comment: @chirlu Note that starting a bounty on a bug report usually tends to be a waste, as the team doesn't generally respond to bounties. For better ways to get attention for this request, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without

Comment: @Sonic: Well, it *did* work – the issue was fixed shortly after I posted the bounty! Admittedly, it appears this would have happened anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was introduced a month ago today as part of a set of changes intended to prevent new stylesheets from interfering with mobile styles.

Aaron fixed it a week ago, as part of the changes for making comment flag/vote tools ever-visible.

Thanks for the report, and sorry for the inconvenience!