# Will there be 2019 monthly product team updates?

Tags: discussion, announcements

Last year, SE began publishing monthly updates from the Developer Affinity & Growth team at [2018 monthly product team updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates). I see that the last update was published in November 2018, as a combined update for September, October, and November.

Fast forward, it's now <s>February 2019</s> June 2019. There hasn't been an update for December 2018 or any month so far in 2019.

Will the update effort be continued into 2019? Also, will we see an update for the <s>two</s> four missing months?

Comment: Not a full answer, but Joe Friend, who maintained the update post, seems no longer to be working for Stack Exchange (no diamond)

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty… Yes, he resigned in December. His account no longer has the staff bit either.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wow, not sure why you made that leap of logic! I left on very good terms with the company and everyone at SO. Working there was a highlight of my career. Stack is filled with wonderful, kind and very smart people. And I'm very bullish on the companies opportunities. The only reason I left was to take an job that was simply too good to pass up. I'm back at a Microsoft where I lead the PM team for http://docs.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the updates will continue. The missing months will likely be captured as part of a larger 'round up' update as we resume. A lot of work has gone into things that, from a user's perspective, are pretty much done (themes, stacks, etc). We have some nice updates to moderator tooling coming out, and some more results and tweaks to talk about for the question wizard soon.

There's an *interim* sort of product manager that's keeping things we've already got scheduled moving, and we will have at least one new PM starting next month, but we can *probably* put out an update between now and then. Thanks for pointing out that we hadn't, I'll get with folks heading that up and see about getting something written.

Note, again, expect a lot of 'finishing touches' kinda stuff, but we'd rather bore you than keep you waiting :)

***Update***

These should resume before the end of this month (February 2019). There will *likely* be some additional posts about the ask question wizard and moderator tools that, while falling into the category of the round-up I was referring to, really should be broken out on their own. But, we'll reference those posts in the cumulative update.

Then, the update process will continue as announced until we find some way of tying the back-end stuff to the front-end stuff so you can just do a cursory search to get an idea of what's being worked on or recently marked completed.

Comment: It's now June, and no update post has been published. When will we see it?

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog, Soon(TM).

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog never? That's my personal theory. (I do not blame Tim, or anyone. SE staff is too busy with other things so don't have time for such things.)

Answer (score 6):

Since the beginning of February 2019, the OP has been asking

> Will there be 2019 monthly product team updates?

It doesn't look like it. Six months, if you include December 2018,  have passed by despite the promise stated

> This [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates) will continue that effort into 2018. (See 2017's updates here.)
>
> **Updates are posted at the beginning of the month**. They cover what was done last month, what is still in progress and new work that will be started in the current month.

Six months have passed by without anyone posting these *monthly* updates, and no one has been adversely affected by their absence. If the team doesn't care, and neither do users on MSE (the request has earned a total of 13 upvotes), should this form of transparency continue to exist at all?

Maybe reporting a trimonthly update would be easier for the team to maintain or even a biannual report at this point of time. As long as the information and the numbers are eventually released there's no great urgency to keep the MSE community continually informed.