# Why can't I just join every community by default?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've recently discovered Stack Exchange and I'm finding it incredibly useful and entertaining. Because I  have many interests, I find myself gradually joining more and more SE communities.

[rant]
Firstly it's a pain retyping the same information every time I join a new one but why should I have to rejoin anyway?  How come I can't just join the lot in one fell swoop?

Okay there may be one or two communities I never use but what does it matter? No-one will suffer because of it.
[/rant]

Can anyone give a convincing reason for not having a single sign-up for all communities?  Thanks.

Comment: By allowing people to sign up to 120+ sites at once, would end up decreasing the "active users" percentage. For example, say woodworking.SE could have 90% participation from it's users, where 90% of 1000 users have asked or answered at least one question. But if tons of people just created accounts on every site so easily, then say there could be 10,000 users on woodworking, and the user participation % would drop dramatically down to like 9%. So no sense in everyone having an account everywhere if they hardly ever visit the site let alone have a question/answer to contribute to the site.

Comment: You don't have to retype anything, just login. All your information is "imported" to any new site.

Answer (score 17):

Today is your lucky day. The problem with the site-specific sign-up and login functionality has been a pain to a lot of users for a few years. This seems technically challenging.

Luckily, they are now working (and actually rolling out) an improved log-in system as you can see in the post [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live). It will allow easy joining other communities when you are logged in already on another site.

---

As for your 'why do I have to join every community one-by-one': If there would just be one user list, network-wide, it would be very hard to see the actual site users. How you can see which users actually signed up for that site and 'committed' themselves to it.