# Why does the mobile web keep logging me off?

Tags: support, login, mobile-web

This is a hard to reproduce bug, since I have totally no clue what happens, but when I use the mobile web interface on both my iOS (iOS versions 8.4 and beta 9) devices it keeps logging me off three times a day.

This seems to happen randomly. In the middle of a session, I suddenly got logged off, and have to log in again. It is strange this mostly happens on SO, but it happened on MSE often too. When it logs me off, I am still logged in to other sites.

Anyone else having this same issue? Any clue on the reason? Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you should be waiting for Stage 3 to go live of the [new login features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live), based on this work break down

> What's next:
>
> - Remember the UI we tested a few months ago? It's coming back.
> - Stage 2: bring other domains into the fold (this is also live now)
> - Stage 3: make cross-domain experience smoother and support browsers that reject third-party cookies in all conditions (**looking at you, Safari**)

(emphasis is mine)

Comment: I did read that too, but didn't think of it apply to mobile safari too.

Comment: If I can blame any Safari, I will, mobile or not ;)