# Active login not recognized on Super User

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, auto-login

While on other Stack Exchange sites like Game Development and Code Review they recognize if I am logged in to Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange and after refresh request from page I am logged in there too. This *autologin* feature does not happen on Super User.

Even if I go to the login page, it does not offer me automaticaly to login with my connected SE account.

I know I am registered on Super User as I even asked a question there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super User is on its own domain name, superuser.com, not under *.stackexchange.com, therefore the current auto-login does not apply.

> **What this means *right now*:**
>
> 1. When you log into any Q&A site on the stackexchange.com domain, you will be automatically logged into all other Q&A sites on the stackexchange.com domain + stackexchange.com itself.
>
>    - Area 51 is excluded from this.
> 2. stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, and other Q&A sites with their own domains will still use the old flow.

<sup>Source: [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live)</sup>

Stage 3 will "make cross-domain experience smoother".