# Why do I now have to login into Stack Exchange if I'm already logged into Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, login

Until about a month or so ago, when I logged into Stack Overflow, I was also logged into Stack Exchange. Occasionally while logged into Stack Overflow, I'll get some status update about a post I made in one of the Stack Exchange communities, but when I click on the link, I have log in a second time. What changed in the last 1 or 2 months to cause this?

---

Additional information - I'm using Chrome, almost always in incognito mode, so there are no saved account names or passwords, but once I logged into SO, I would also be logged into SE.

Comment: What sites, exactly? I think that the global login still needs manual login for different domains, e.g. Super User, Server Fault, etc. See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262211/active-login-not-recognized-on-super-user

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask - The last one was SE Aviation. I think it's also happened with SE Computer Science and SE Mathematics.

Comment: do you have third-party cookies disabled? Explanation [in this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other/312956#312956) what happens under the hood.

Comment: @rene - Chrome announced it would phase out all third party cookies back around August 2019. Maybe that has happened by now.

Comment: Chrome 84 blocks third-party cookies that aren't set with the SameSite attribute, but a quick glance at the browser console on SO seems to indicate that it's set properly.

Comment: @Mithical - At least for incognito mode, there's an option to enable third party cookies (turn off the disabling of third party cookies), which appears to be working.

Comment: These seems to be a bug