# "Join this community" doesn't appear for sites not subdomains of stackexchange.com

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, top-bar

I just visited Ask Ubuntu (`askubuntu.com`) while logged into Stack Exchange, and noticed that "join this community" doesn't appear:

[image: sign up - log in - etc]

It is similarly broken on Math Overflow (`mathoverflow.net`). It works, however, on all sites that are subdomains of `stackexchange.com`, like Mathematics (`math.stackexchange.com`) and Academia.

I'm using Google Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 on Windows 8.1 Update 1.

(I don't know if this can actually be fixed, given how cookie security works, but I figured Stack Exchange should be aware of the issue.)

Comment: Are you logged into another Stack Exchange account? I can't repro this (I get `join this community` there)

Comment: I did, a long time ago, accidentally have a different account on Stack Overflow. I have never logged into it anywhere else. @Zizouz212

Comment: Not really a bug. As Adam explains in comments to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260583/152859), you must first have account on those sites to see "join this community" when not logged in

Comment: Here's what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G2b5Q.png Are you logged in even *one* SE account?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I am logged in with this account. Visiting SO, SU, SF, or Area 51 shows me fully logged in. I get "join this community" on all sites (where I haven't fully registered) that are subdomains of stackexchange.com.

Comment: But you see "log in" and "sign up" for askubuntu? Strange..

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, that's old info. "join this community" is for sites you *don't* have an account on.

Comment: @BenN I'm retagging this as [support] (see my answer) since I'm pretty sure this is normal (albeit unintuitive) behaviour. Let me know if you're seeing something different and I'll dig in deeper.

Comment: Thanks for this question. I just ran into the same problem. Is there a list of SEs that aren't on subdomains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When did you log in last time? Not visited a site, but actually logged in?

We didn't have a good way to "grandfather" cross-domain sessions and link them up together, so when universal login went live, people logged in to different domains within the network potentially ended up with ungrouped sessions for each domain.

In Safari, this behaviour is unfortunately normal since Safari does not accept third-party cookies under any circumstances. In other browsers, assuming you have third-party cookies allowed (or at least white-listed the domains involved), you can "fix" this by logging in on a domain that still gives you the "sign up" and "log in" links instead of "join this community". That should link up your new session with the existing one(s) and kick off login requests for the remaining domains as well.

Comment: I had logged in on a different computer just a few days ago, but my last login on this machine was a good long while back. Creating an account on Ask Ubuntu the "sign in" way fixed it on Math Overflow too.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue. I was logged into https://stackoverflow.com/ but https://superuser.com wasn't showing the "Join this community" button. It seems this was because I had tracking protection turned on in my browser's settings.

I had to do the following:

1. Turn off my browser's Tracking Protection on both domains.
2. Log out of StackOverflow
3. Log back into StackOverflow
4. Refresh SuperUser