# Don't always have a 'Join this Community' Button

Tags: discussion, bug, login, user-accounts

I already have accounts on a bunch of Stack Exchange sites. Mostly when I'm looking at posting on a new SE site, I can see a blue 'Join this Community' button, which gives me a painless "extend my existing account to include this SE" experience.  :+1:

E.g. (stolen from another question):

[image: Enter link description here]

But on other Stack Exchange sites, I just get regular "Login / SignUp" buttons.

What's the deal here? Is that supposed to happen? Are some SE sites different? If I SignUp with the right credentials, will it all get joined together anyway? What happens if I use some variant of my email-address (e.g. `gmail` vs `googlemail`) will I be able to sync the accounts back together after the fact?

---

For reference, in this particular case it's the Super User SE, but I'm pretty sure I've seen this intermittently elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by Tracking Protection.

Solved, by this answer on the duplicate question:
*https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313156/304830*

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: It turns out I'm not such an idiot....
That "JtC" button still takes me to the same "SignUp from scratch" page. Not the "link my existing SE account to this" that I'm looking for.

=====================

Ignore me ... I'm an idiot.

This was the screen I saw when I went to Super User:

[image]

Immediately under the header bar, is a big banner with the "Join the Community" button. Apparently I missed that. :rolling-eyes-at-self:

I would guess that I [pattern-matched it as a banner ad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness).

If anyone sees this, who has control over this ... I would encourage:

1. Keep the "standard" JtC button, as well as anything else.
2. Maybe do something to make that *not* look like a banner ad? No idea what that would entail; I'm not a UX-designer :(