# Login once for all sites using the mobile website

Tags: support, login, mobile-web, mobile-safari

On mobile Safari, on my iPhone, I needed to login for Stack Overflow, then again for Super User, etc.

Shouldn't one login suffice for all 160 sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That isn't possible unfortunately. It has to do with the way Safari handles third-party (logon) cookies. That prevents SE to make one global authentication cookie which can be sent to every site to authenticate you.
Instead, they have to revert to a method that doesn't work globally.

So we are stuck until Apple thinks it is a good idea to allow such authentication cookies, or SE finds another way to do it.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate but I couldn't find it. Maybe someone else knows where to find it...

Comment: It's explained here: [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/307988)

Comment: Ah yes. That was the post I was looking for. It is mentioned as Stage 3 there.

Comment: @PatrickHofman With all the changes to Safari over the past years, is this perhaps now possible?