# I am logged in but some sites want me to log in again

Tags: support, notifications, login, user-accounts

I had been interacting with a bunch of different Stack Exchange sites during the last couple days. One of my actions was to update a question to a site I had signed up for a while back, but the site was one I don't normally do stuff on (superuser). The question I updated was [Intermittantly can't edit Excel cell](https://superuser.com/questions/1104286/intermittantly-cant-edit-excel-cell).

Later, I saw the red box indicating someone had commented on my question. I went to that page and the commenter had posted that my update had apparently been recorded as posted by a temp/anonymous user.

My questions are:

- if the update was done by someone other than my main account (according to the system), why did it send me the comment notification?
- If instead the system knows this temp account was actually me (because I got the notification), why does it want me to sign in to do anything, unlike my more commonly visited sites which I had just been doing work on?
- Shouldn't all of the sites I can see from my main account page be linked?

Maybe the solution is as simple as requesting that all of my Stack Exchange sites be linked to my main account by an admin.

Comment: You get a notification when someone edits your post. And they're not forums  :-)

Comment: @Mithrandir: That makes sense. It may well have been the notification was for my own edit to my question, but the commenter was so fast off the mark that he commented within a minute of my post. So I assumed he was the cause of the notification because, of course, I wouldn't get notified for editing my own post.   ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue with having to log-in again on some sites and my hypothesis is that this depends on what the site's domain name is:

If I am logged in on `linguistics.stackexchange.com`, I am automatically logged in to

- `math.stackexchange.com`
- `cs.stackexchange.com`
- `meta.stackexchange.com`

but I have to log in again for

- `stackoverflow.com`
- `superuser.com`

and my assumption is that it's because the latter two are not `.stackexchange.com` sites so my browser thinks it's a different site I have not logged in to yet, although SE corretly collects notification from all sites in my profile.

I don't think it's possible to get around this, though.

Comment: your analyses is sound: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login Most cookies expire only after months, some after an half year and some in 2055. But if one of the cookies is expired re-authentication is expected.