# Auto profile-merge feature – can it be disabled for an account?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, network-profile

I've had multiple profiles past last years. I wan't to create one stable profile now. When I once tried, it was auto-merged to some ancient account whose cookies were apparently still around. Can this feature be blocked for an account, so that it's stable-not-merging profile?

Comment: Multiple accounts were never really supported, it just happened to work. After the roll-out of [universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) that scenario became definitely unsupported.

Comment: If what you *want* is a single profile why wouldn't you want them merged?

Comment: @Cai - Because I would assume its connected to the fact that every question and ever answered submitted by a profile is considered by the system that determines if you should have the previllage of submitting a question or answer to a question.  I can't find a good reason for multiple anonymous profiles.

Answer (score 4):

We don't explicitly support the ability to run multiple accounts simultaneously, so we also don't have any features that would aid a user in doing that. This includes any feature to disable merges for an account - we'll just never incorporate something like that.

So long as you never do something that causes both accounts to have the same verified email address (such as inserting it into your notification email in your preferences, or adding a credential that uses the same email), the accounts should never trigger an auto-merge. However, if you *do* something like that, there's nothing we can do to prevent the auto-merge from completing.