# Network Login Troubleshooting fails on Messaging whereas Caniuse.com tests positive

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, authentication, auto-login

A couple of months ago, I was forced to switch to the [Vivaldi browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_(web_browser)) which I do happen to like a lot.

The Vivaldi browser might be considered the spiritual successor to the Opera browser, sharing the same original author. However, unlike Opera, Vivaldi is almost entirely based on Chrome using the very same Blink layout engine.

Nonetheless, one problem keeps on pestering me:
**I am required to log in for each and every of my Stack Exchange accounts separately.**

Running the [Network Login Troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) indeed reports a problem with `Messaging` and therefore [`stackauth.com`](https://stackauth.com).

However, testing the very same Vivaldi version 2.1.1337.36 (stable) with the independent [Caniuse.com tester](http://tests.caniuse.com/?feat=x-doc-messaging&ua=) yields an all green positive test result.

Could it be that a bug in the Stack Exchange code is keeping me from successfully logging in across all my Stack Exchange network accounts?

Comment: I think SE test is broken. I also get a "failed" with ordinary Chrome 70, and can login just fine without being logged out every time.

Comment: You should allow third-party cookies.

Comment: If it **is not a cookie issue** then it is some [failure with the script loading the images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100) after you have logged in on one site. Can you check the developer console or have a network trace from your client to the SE server park?

Comment: The messaging failed bug has been reported earlier [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298028/messaging-failed-houston-didnt-get-contacted) (yes, that post is also mine) /cc @ShadowWizard

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)*

Comment: @rene Allowing all third-party cookies is the most stupid thing one can do if you care anything about your privacy. However, I am happy to selectively allow a singled-out off-domain cookie.

Comment: I only care about that stuff works. I guess allowing cookies for .stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, serverfault.com, askubuntu.com, stackapps.com and mathoverflow.com should make the universal login feature to function correctly.