# Network login failing

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I am unable to log in, for example, to [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour). Using the latest Firefox on Windows 10, I already tried disabling addons like [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) and [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin). After clicking on *Login* on Super User, it just shows the login screen where I can choose Google/Facebook or enter username/password, but I cannot log in with the Stack Exchange account. I also tried disabling HTTPs-only mode (Firefox built-in).

I have found *https://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help*, but I am not sure if it is still relevant (it should be removed if not). It shows me *Messaging failed* both in Firefox and also in Edge on the same PC and also on Firefox on Android.

Are there any recent troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Try disabling *all* addons and userscripts, sometimes something that appears "innocent" and not related is causing such problems. I'd look for a recent example.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard is it possible that even after disabling addons, something saved (some site-specific storage or FF settings/permissions) will prevent the login?

Comment: Yeah, so better clear cache as well, just to be sure. :)

Comment: When you login on superuser.com, any errors in the console? Did you get two cookies: prov and acct?

Comment: @rene no errors, just the `prov` cookie. I already tried with all addons disabled. Can you please try the `network-login-help` page if it works for you and if it should work? Because that says `Your browser does not support the HTML5 postMessage feature` even in Edge on Windows or FF on Android.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard clear cache for which domains?

Comment: that test page is broken for 6 to 8 years by now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298028/messaging-failed-houston-didnt-get-contacted

Comment: @rene Would be nice to either fix it or remove it, because I found it via google... Anyway, manually entering login+password into superuser worked, but it's still mystery why I wasn't logged in automatically like other SO sites.

Comment: because Universal login is broken due to stricter browser security

Comment: So it's a known issue without a fix?

Comment: You have to fix all the browsers or SE has to redesign their universal login again.