# How does stackoverflow detect whether i'm a logged in user?

Tags: discussion, auto-login

So when I enter https://stackoverflow.com/, I don't see anything on XHR. How on earth does the server know who I am? :)

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login

Comment: did you heard about processing cookies at server side?