I can't seem to log onto other sites without signing-in
A while back, I went from Game Development to Arqade, and I didn't need to sign-in to log into Arqade, but now that I'm starting to go to Server Fault, I need to sign-in. Why didn't it ask me to sign-in for Game Development and Arqade, and it is asking me now?

I mean, this isn't really a problem, I'm just wondering why it is doing this now.

Not a full answer, but IIRC there are certain sites that have separate login, then the rest of the smaller sites share a single one. I think it’s domain-related.  Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login

Oh, well that makes sense. Ok. Thanks.
